# Convert Json data to Python DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is my first time accessing an API / working with json data so if anyone can point me towards a good resource for understanding how to work with it I'd really appreciate it.

Specifically though, I have json data in this form:

```
{"result": { "code": "OK", "msg": "" },"report_name":"DAILY","columns":["ad","ad_impressions","cpm_cost_per_ad","cost"],"data":[{"row":["CP_CARS10_LR_774470","966","6.002019","5.797950"]}],"total":["966","6.002019","5.797950"],"row_count":1}
```

I understand this structure but I don't know how to get it into a DataFrame properly.

Comment: Could you post the whole JSON please.

Comment: You might be better off parsing out the column names and data and creating a dataframe yourself, rather than use the pd.read_json class. So parse out json['columns'] and json['data'][0]['row'] for columns and rows respectively, then construct your data frame as you would normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the structure of your `json`, presumably you will have several rows for your data and in my opinion it will make more sense to build the dataframe yourself.

This code uses `columns` and `data` to build a dataframe:

```
In [12]:

import json
import pandas as pd
​
with open('... path to your json file ...') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        columns = obj['columns']
        data = obj['data']
        l = []
        for d in data:
            l += [d['row']]
        df = pd.DataFrame(l, index=None, columns=columns)

df
Out[12]:
ad  ad_impressions  cpm_cost_per_ad cost
0   CP_CARS10_LR_774470 966 6.002019    5.797950
```

As for the rest of the data, in your `json`, I guess you could e.g. use the totals for checking your dataframe,

```
In [14]:

sums = df.sum(axis=0)
obj['total']
for i in range(0,3):
    if (obj['total'][i] != sums[i+1]):
        print "error in total"

In [15]:

if obj['row_count'] != len(df.index):
    print "error in row count"
```

As for the rest of the data in the `json`, it is difficult for me to know if anything else should be done.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check pandas documentation. Specifically,

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Pandas supports reading json to dataframe

Comment: I get an error with pd.read_json(response) stating "arrays must all be the same length". The problem is that there is a final row, "Total" which has excludes ad names, I don't see any documentation on how to handle this from the above link